# How to align to parent div horizontally and fixed vertically?

Tags: css

I would like to align some elements - the arrow buttons in this example - horizontally to the edges of the containing div. However they should be vertically fixed in the viewport.

This example has a single image. In practice clicking the arrows would update the image to another, usually of different ratio and size. The reason for fixed positioning vertically is to avoid the arrow buttons jumping up and down vertically on change of image. Centering them vertically on the image causes them to move up and down.

By changing the css of .leftmodal and .rightmodal to position:fixed instead of absolute, they do stick vertically, but then they escape from the image div horizontally.

Another note, if relevant, the image does and must shrink when the browser window is reduced in width.

Any way to do this without javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #imgbox {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    .leftModal, .rightModal {
        font-size: 32px;
        border-radius: 24px;
        padding: 0 10px 6px 10px;
        top: 45%;
        position: absolute;
        /*position: fixed;*/
    }
    .leftModal {
        left: 0;
    }
    .rightModal {
        right: 0;
    }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="imgbox">
        <img src="https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/7D7mJjY7GEA9.png">
        <button type="button" class="leftModal">&lt;</button>
        <button type="button" class="rightModal">&gt;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a unit that doesn't depend on image size, like "vw" or "vh", on property "top" (e.g. top: 45vw).

I suggest giving a fixed height to your #imgbox, and then place the image absolute to the container, adding object-fit: cover (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit); fixing arrows with variable images can have a bad ux because of layout shift.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I realise now I had heard of vh units but just never thought to try that. This does the job well.